# Save not working when selecting specific columns using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have database tables, `Employee`, `EmpCompRequirement`, and `CompCategory`.

`CompCategory` is a list of training competencies.  `EmpCompCategory` is a way of assigning whether an employee requires a training competency.

Here's the basic structure (but there's many more columns in `Employee`).

[image: tables]

Using Entity Framework Core, I want to select the EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName and a list of all the employee's records in EmpCompRequirement.

So I use this

```
Employee _employee = _context.Employees
                       .Include(_ => _.EmpCompRequirements)
                       .Select(_ => new Employee
                       {
                           EmployeeId = _.EmployeeId,
                           FirstName = _.FirstName,
                           LastName = _.LastName,
                           EmpCompRequirements = _.EmpCompRequirements
                       })
                       .Single(_ => _.EmployeeId == empId);
```

In my program's form, it can Add and Remove records in the `EmpCompRequirements` within `_employee`.  The code correctly does this.  However when I call EF Core's Save Changes, it doesn't update the database.

However if I were to do this:

```
Employee _employee = _context.Employees
                       .Include(_ => _.EmpCompRequirements)
                       .Single(_ => _.EmployeeId == empId);
```

Then the Save Changes works correctly.

But this selects all columns in the Employee table, which I do not use at any point here (there is over 100 of them).

How do a select only these columns and it still be able to add and remove records in `EmpCompRequirement` with Save Changes.

Comment: You need to attach the returned Employee instances to the context so they are being tracked. This is because once you start projecting what you want using a Select then the projected instances will not be automatically attached to the DbContext for tracking.

Comment: @Igor OMG I spent ages on this and all I needed was `_context.Attach(_employee);`  Thanks that's worked.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

use LINQ query is more practical to unde

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).